# Drizzle ORM : Internal error: Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "users.contacts"

Tags: node.js, database, orm, backend, drizzle

I'm using Drizzle ORM with PostgreSQL, and this is how my schema looks. In a simple manner, there is a 'users' table and a 'contacts' table. Each user can have multiple contacts.

```
export const users = pgTable("users", {
  id: uuid("id").defaultRandom().primaryKey(),
  email: text("email").unique().notNull(),
  about: varchar("about", { length: 100 }),
  created_at: timestamp("created_at").defaultNow(),
  workspace_id: uuid("workspace_id").references(() => workspaces.id, {
    onDelete: "cascade",
    onUpdate: "cascade"
  })
});

export const usersRelations = relations(users, ({ one, many }) => ({
  permission: one(permissions, {
    fields: [users.email],
    references: [permissions.user_email]
  }),
  contacts: many(contacts,{
    relationName: 'users_contacts',
  })
}));

export const contactType = pgEnum(....);

export const contacts = pgTable("contacts", {
  id: uuid("id").defaultRandom().primaryKey(),
  type: contactType("type").default("phone").notNull(),
  value: text("value").notNull(),
  created_at: timestamp("created_at").defaultNow(),
  user_email: text("user_email")
    .references(() => users.email, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
      onUpdate: "cascade"
    })
    .unique()
    .notNull()
});

export const contactsRelations = relations(contacts, ({ many }) => ({
  users: many(users)
}));
```

but when i do like this

```
const workspaceUsers = await db.query.users.findMany({
    where: eq(users.workspace_id, loggedWorkspace.data.id),
    with: {
      permission:true,
      contacts: true
    }
  });
```

However, I don't know why I'm encountering this error. Please let me know how I can fix it.

```
⨯ Internal error: Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "users.contacts"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so basically I was doing it in wrong way, I just need to use relationName on both side like this

```
export const usersRelations = relations(users, ({ man }) => ({
  contacts: many(contacts, {
    relationName: "users_contacts"
  })
}));

export const contactsRelations = relations(contacts, ({ one }) => ({
  user: one(users, {
    fields: [contacts.user_email],
    references: [users.email],
    relationName: "users_contacts"
  })
}));
```